# How do I remove HD encryption in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

Recently we suffered a crash of Ubuntu. After trying to boot the system back up we are being asked to Unlock the disk /dev/disk/by-uuid/de2ce-fdsfsd-etc and a prompt to enter in a passphrase. None of us remember ever creating a passphrase for this. Is this something that's turned on by default on Ubuntu and how do I remove this so I can get this system booted back up?

Comment: cntrl-c 
is it continue booting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the file system was encrypted with [LUKS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Unified_Key_Setup).

Unfortunately, there is no way to get pass it unless you know the passphrase to decrypt the file system.

Comment: I was afraid of that :( Thanks Rilindo, I'll see if he can remember anything.

Comment: It's not part of the default installation steps; one has to request it and then go through choosing a passphrase, etc. Like Trevor says, it might be possible that the device is not necessary for booting nor that your data is necessarily on that device. Although the 'etc' in the name name sounds bad. Perhaps you can create a new logical volume?

Comment: In that case, Trevor will need to boot from a rescue disk and hope his data is not on the same file system as /etc.

Comment: Turns out the guy who installed it used a common password so we were able to get back in to the system. Thanks for your replies, much appreciated!